# How to cache specific resources while disable cache is on in Chrome

Tags: caching, google-chrome-devtools

**Is it possible to cache specific resources while developing with `disable cache` option turned on in Chrome Dev Tools?**

One might want to cache `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css` while testing local projects with caching disabled, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't using DevTools. The disable cache disables the entire cache possible.

You may **star** a recent [feature request in the Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591350) asking for just this feature. Please remember that +1, me too, and any other un-constructive comments are not needed. Simply login and click the star beside the issue number in the left sidebar. That will let the developers know others want this functionality as well.